# How to show the time when task was created by using react

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity

I want to show the time when a task was created in my todo app using ethereum.

I get `task` which include `content` and `time`, and set task by state in this code.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    tasks: [],
  }
}
・・・
for (var k = 1; k <= taskCount; k++) {
  const task = await todoList.methods.tasks(k).call()
  this.setState({
    tasks: [...this.state.tasks, task]
  })
}
```

Then, I use `map` to show `tasks` array and `time`.

```
{ this.props.tasks.map((task, key) => {
  return(
    <div key={key}>
      <p>{task.content}</p>    
      <p>{task.time}</p>
    </div>
  )
})}
```

As a result, I got numbers like this

```
1555650125
1555651118
1555651169
1555664902
```

So, I changed `{task.time}` to `{Date(checkin.checkintime)}` on order to convert that number to normal time.
However, the result shows only number.

```
Sat Apr 20 2019 09:20:57 
Sat Apr 20 2019 09:20:57 
Sat Apr 20 2019 09:20:57 
Sat Apr 20 2019 09:20:57
```

I wrote this code in order to check `Data()` is working, then I could get correct answer.

```
for (var k = 1; k <= taskCount; k++) {
  const task = await todoList.methods.tasks(k).call()
  const tasktime = new Date(task.checkintime * 1000)
  console.log(tasktime)

  this.setState({
    tasks: [...this.state.tasks, task]
  })
}
```

```
Fri Apr 19 2019 14:02:05 
Fri Apr 19 2019 14:18:38 
Fri Apr 19 2019 14:19:29 
Fri Apr 19 2019 18:08:22
```

Could you give me any advise to show the time inside map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this section, I assume, `task` is the new task which was just created. You can update the task.checkintime property, with your time string:

```
const task = await todoList.methods.tasks(k).call()
task.checkintime = new Date(task.checkintime * 1000).toDateString();

this.setState({
    tasks: [...this.state.tasks, task]
})
```

Which means it'll then be accessible within your map:

```
{ this.props.tasks.map((task, key) => {
return(
  <div key={key}>
    <p>{task.content}</p>    
    <p>{task.checkintime}</p>
  </div>
)
```

This will take https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString and assign a string representation of your date on `task.checkintime`.

If you want to do different formatting, take a look at [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) so you can formatted your Date object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I tried, this error come up "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Sun Apr 21 2019 21:08:53. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: Sorry, this is because we have just assigned a Date object to `task.checkintime`. I've updated my answer to convert the Date object to a string representation with some links to different formatting.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question. I got only `Apr 21 2019`, but I also want to show `hour` and `minute`. Do you have any idea? I couldn't find how to do that.

Comment: You can replace `.toDateString()` with `.toLocaleString()`, this has many more options available to it, listed here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString.  Read up on it within this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date/34015511#34015511 where it's spoken about.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I greatly appreciate your support !!

Comment: No problems! If you could accept my answer that would be fantastic, thank you :)

Comment: Sorry I got to do that. Done!

Answer (score 0):

`task.time` is time defined by the [UNIX time epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) system. From this you can convert in to any format.
Not sure what you want to show but `new Date(task.time)` seems like a step in the right direction. You can refer to the [Date reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) or [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) if it's not enough.